# how to avoid the automatic rounding of decimal value in extjs ?

Tags: extjs3

how to avoid the automatic rounding of decimal value in Extensible java script? For example if i enter 2.003 it will rounded as 2 or some times if i enter 2.039 it is accepting as 2.0388888887 please help me out.

Answer (score -1):

For numberfields you can use [decimal precision config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.NumberField-cfg-decimalPrecision)

The maximum precision to display after the decimal separator (defaults to 2)

Technically it is simply toFixed:

```
fixPrecision : function(value) {
    var nan = isNaN(value);

    if (!this.allowDecimals || this.decimalPrecision == -1 || nan || !value) {
        return nan ? '' : value;
    }

    return parseFloat(parseFloat(value).toFixed(this.decimalPrecision));
},
```